# Scroll child div while scroling on parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

When user scrolls on parent div, child should scroll till end and then page scroll should continue.

I tried this reverse logic 
[Scrolling in child div ( fixed ) should scroll parent div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953228/scrolling-in-child-div-fixed-should-scroll-parent-div)

But doesn't work. please suggest how to get this working.

```css
.scrolling-child{ height: 50px; width:400px; border:1px solid green; overflow:scroll; }
.parent { height: 5000px; width:100%; padding: 20px 0; border:1px solid red; overflow:scroll;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="scrolling-child">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the parent has no overflow so how can it scroll? Also why would you want that functionality?

Comment: Have added scroll also. This snippet is a small part of my webpage. I need this for better look and feel.

Comment: Again, the inner content isn't large enough to cause any scrolling so I don't see what you want to happen

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly just add position:fixed; to the scrolling-child div. See below.

```css
.scrolling-child{height: 50px; width:400px; border:1px solid green; overflow:scroll; position:fixed;}

.parent {height: 5000px; width:100%; padding: 20px 0; border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="scrolling-child">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think that is what OP is looking for. How I interpret the question is OP wants the user to scroll on the parent div, and while the child div is not at the bottom, scroll down until child div end is reached. Then continue scrolling the parent div. This is all without moving the mouse off of the parent div. My interpretation at least.